# Install centos7 on mounted disk

Tags: centos7, installation

I have a centos 7 machine, and I attached an external disk.
I would like to install centos 7 on this mounted disk, so that I can disconnect this disk, and then boot from it by attaching it to another machine.

How do I do this?  I do not have a GUI, this is all on the command line.
Can kickstart be made to work locally like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not install CentOS using CLI in to a external drive.

Reading the [official documentation](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Making_Media/) only mention a way to do the installation: create bootable physical media.

You can try to unplug your disk from the machine, plug the empty disk and install CentOS there. Then you can unplugged it  and plug again you original disk.

Comment: Unplugging a disk is illadvised as the machine is bound to have running procs that will attempt to page, but it's a nice idea.  Thanks